# this.state is not defined in initMap

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

i have used initMap() function to render google map in react js. I want to update the state on click event of map. my problem is that when i using this.setState() inside initMap() function it gives error of **TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.** please suggest me can i implement this another way.

```
import {
  Map,
  InfoWindow,
  GoogleApiWrapper,
  LoadingContainer,
  Marker,
} from "google-maps-react";
class DrawingMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.initMap = this.initMap.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      latLngList: [],
    };
  }
  initMap(mapProps, map) {
    var self = this;
    const { google } = mapProps;
    var poly;
    let label = 1;
    console.log(this.state);
    function addCircle(location) {
      let latlng = {};
      latlng.lat = location.lat();
      latlng.lng = location.lng();
      this.setState({
        latLngList: latlng,
      });
      var square = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        strokeColor: "orange",
        fillColor: "orange",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        scale: 10,
      };
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: square,
        label: {
          text: label.toString(),
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      });
      label++;
    }
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeColor: "orange",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 5,
    });
    poly.setMap(map);
    if (toggle) poly.setMap(null);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
      var path = poly.getPath();
      path.push(event.latLng);
      addCircle(event.latLng);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        onReady={this.initMap}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 19.993982, lng: 73.790416 }}
        mapType={"hybrid"}
        zoom={15}
      ></Map>
    );
  }
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: key,
  libraries: ["drawing"],
  LoadingContainer: LoadingContainer,
})(DrawingMap);
```

Comment: have yout tried changing addCircle to an arrow function?

Comment: yes i have tried with arrow function but it gives error ***'addCircle' is not defined  no-undef***

Answer (score 1):

React.Component doesn't auto bind methods to itself.
To solve the issue either you change addCircle to an arrow function but also map click event listener
or easier just using stored this reference like this
[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/thisstate-is-not-defined-in-initmap-jxytg?file=/src/MapComponent.jsx)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Map,
  InfoWindow,
  GoogleApiWrapper,
  LoadingContainer,
  Marker,
} from "google-maps-react";
class DrawingMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.initMap = this.initMap.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      latLngList: [],
    };
  }
  initMap(mapProps, map) {
    var self = this;
    const { google } = mapProps;
    var poly;
    let label = 1;
    console.log(this.state);
    function addCircle(location) {
      let latlng = {};
      latlng.lat = location.lat();
      latlng.lng = location.lng();
      self.setState({
        latLngList: latlng,
      });
      var square = {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        strokeColor: "orange",
        fillColor: "orange",
        fillOpacity: 1,
        scale: 10,
      };
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        icon: square,
        label: {
          text: label.toString(),
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
      });
      label++;
    }
    poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeColor: "orange",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 5,
    });
    poly.setMap(map);
    //if (toggle) poly.setMap(null);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
      var path = poly.getPath();
      path.push(event.latLng);
      addCircle(event.latLng);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        onReady={this.initMap}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 19.993982, lng: 73.790416 }}
        mapType={"hybrid"}
        zoom={15}
      ></Map>
    );
  }
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: key,
  libraries: ["drawing"],
  LoadingContainer: LoadingContainer,
})(DrawingMap);
```

Comment: thanks! finally solved this issue using arrow function.